# LINQ join on datatables with multi column primary key using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write an api which does data comparison. I get 2 tables (of same schema) dynamically. User will also pass primary key which supports multi column PrimaryKey.

I need to do Row comparison and only return extra rows in first table.

As of now 
I could check if schema is matching or not and through exception if both are not matching,
Check all the columns in PrimaryKey (DataColumn[] type) and if any columns are missing then throw exception.

Then to avoid duplicate rows I am setting the DataTable PrimaryKey with user passed PrimaryKey in try catch and throwing exception in case it fails (This fails if there are any duplicates Pks in the table)

Now got stuck at A-B. I could write simple SQL which does the job for me:

```
Select A.Id, A.Name
From    SampleDB..Emp1 A Left Outer Join SampleDB..Emp2 B On A.Id = B.Id
Where B.Id is null
```

**A.Id = B.Id** is dynamic in my case. If it is multi Column primary key I need to make this part dynamic.

I got an implementation which is kind of hardcoding which will not work in my case

Here is the code:

```
var tablesJoinend = from t1 in MasterSource.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                join t2 in TargetSource.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() on t1["yourcolumn"] equals t2["yourcolumn"]
                                select t1;

            DataTable output = tablesJoinend.CopyToDataTable();
```

in this join condition becomes hardcoded. For my case, I need to make it dynamic based on primaryKey

Any suggestion on how to do it using c#?

Comment: If you renamed t1 to A and t2 to B, and "yourcolumn" to Id, you'd have `on A["Id"] equals B["Id"]`.  You could explain why you think that's less "dynamic" than what you detailed in the T-SQL?  i.e. could you explain why that doesn't work for you?  Without that criteria, it's hard for someone to respond with something that *does* fulfil the criteria.

Comment: What if the user table got different field as Pk? Say EmpId. Another user want to compare Sale Data and Pk is SalesId. So I want to generate the query dynamically. Hope I am more clear now

Comment: Well, you can use a declarative syntax to declare something that isn't known until run-time.  You *could* a predicate method or delegate to perform all or just the dynamic part of the where predicate--where that method or delegate knows how to compare the dynamic list of fields.